# OpenGL VBO - Array Stride wrong?

Tags: java, android, arrays, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

Now I hope you can help me with that problem, I have had for several days, without finding any solution. I feel, I've tried everything out to fix that problem, but none of them worked.

First of all:
I have some Objects in my scene, that use VBOs for rendering. Nothing else, no other quads, polys, etc. only the ones in the screenshots, that will follow.

My generation-Code of the VBOs is very simple and hopefully clear and comprehensable:

**Generating VBO**

```
public boolean buffer() {
    FloatBuffer[] vertexBuffer = new FloatBuffer[1];
    vertexBuffer[0] = FloatBufferFactory.create(this.triangles.size() * 3 * 11);

    for (Triangle triangle : this.triangles) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].position.x);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].position.y);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].position.z);

            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].normal.x);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].normal.y);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].normal.z);

            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].color.r);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].color.g);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].color.b);

            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].uvset.x);
            vertexBuffer[0].put(triangle.vertex[i].uvset.y);
        }
    }

    vertexBuffer[0].position(0);

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, this.buffer, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer[0].capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer[0], GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    return true;
}
```

It's very simple: My own function in FloatBufferFactory creates a Floatbuffer with count-of-triangles * 3 * 11 * 4 Bytes.
Then I put the data in it, for each Vertex of the triangles.

My logic: 12 Bytes (3 * 4 Bytes) for one vertexposition, 12 Bytes for one normalposition, 12 Bytes for Vertexcolordata and 8 Bytes for UV-coordinates.

**Rendering**

When I render the mesh, I use following function as simple as the other one:

```
public void render() {
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer[0]);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeVertex, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0]);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeNormal, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 12);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeColor, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 24);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeUV, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 36);        

    this.passMaterialUniforms();
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this.triangles.size() * 3);
}
```

Now, my logic, as I understood it:
All data in Bytes for one Vertex is: 12Bytes (position) + 12Bytes (normal) + 12Bytes (color) + 8Bytes (uv) -> makes in conclusion: 44 Bytes for each Vertex, so the next Vertex should be after 44 Bytes. -> Stride: 44 Bytes for each data.

The next idea was to set the start offset: 0Bytes for position, 12Bytes for normal, 24Bytes for color and 36Bytes for uv.
So far so good.

**The main problem**

Now there seems to happen something very, very weird in the programm. After creating more than 3 Objects or so, the objects that were generated after the first three, are displayed wrong.

Here the screenshots:
First example and try ( Generated: 5 Torus in a row):
[image: As you can see, in the first picture the 4. and 5. Torus ( Tori?!) are distorted and look like beans or lenses, or something like that.]

Second try ( Generated 2 Spheres, 1 Torus, another Sphere, another Torus):
[image: the 3. Sphere ( 4. generated object) looks quite normal, when you just look at the positions, but the texture-coordinates are very strange.]

As you can see, in the first picture the 4. and 5. Torus ( Tori?!) are distorted and look like beans or lenses, or something like that.
In the second picture, the 3. Sphere ( 4. generated object) looks quite normal, when you just look at the positions, but the texture-coordinates are very strange.

So why is that? How can I fix that problem?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to the way you enabled the attrib pointer.

You wrote this:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeVertex, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0]);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeNormal, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 12);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeColor, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 24);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeUV, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, this.buffer[0] + 36);
```

It should be like this:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeVertex, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, 0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeNormal, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, 12);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeColor, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, 24);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(BaseActivity.activeShader.attributeUV, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 44, 36);
```

I suggest anyway to define some constants for the offset calculations.

In my C engine I based everything with the sizeof function

Comment: This seems the answer, as when a VBO is bound, the last argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` is a byte-offset into the currently bound buffer, starting from 0.

Comment: @chrise: Hey, we are in two ;-) I have made the same mistake the first time I have approached this topic  ;-) glad to have helped.

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Huh, feels good man ;) We both won't do the same mistake again! :D